# Add column to database via controller in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi so i have a project that is already done but there was a request to add a new column to a specific table i was thinking of a way to add that new column to my table without using migrate or php artisan method to it. i was thinking if it is posible to implement it in the controller. say for example the column name is isOut then values should be `false` not `null`. thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Schema Builder inside a controller as well as in migrations.

Just include `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`

Then run this inside a controller function:

```
Schema::table('table_name', function($table)
{
    $table->boolean('isOut')->default(false);
});
```

Take care only to run the controller function once, for example by creating a special route to this function with a random string.